# Problems using XRDP - screen seems blank

Tags: 20.04, xrdp

As many others before me, I have a blank screen when using XRDP to remote access my Ubuntu 20.04. But strangely enough, when I open the File manager then it appears on my remote screen and not on my local Ubuntu monitor. Other programs show up on the Ubuntu monitor when started and not on the remote. If I try to open a file from the remote computer then it opens up on my Ubuntu monitor.

Since most existing post about blank XRDP screens are really old then I think it is in place to get an up-to-date answer.